# Ajax content still not crawable // although hashtag included

Tags: ajax

first of all - yes, I have tried to find a solution in the web.
I have made everything as far as I can see which is proposed here at google : 
https://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html - in order to make my ajax-content crawable:

The url: http://www.example.com
The ajax-request: http://www.example.com/#!ajaxcontent.html
The googlebot-request: http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=ajaxcontent.html
The 301-redirect on gb-request:  http://www.example.com/ajaxcontent.html

If you try to access the url of the redirect directly you can see all the html-content without problems (pages are valid too). The 301-redirect is working just fine.

I am not really an expert in this area and thats my first time trying to make my ajax-content crawable. But if I "fetch page as googlebot", I get this:

---

URL: http://www.example.com/#!ajaxcontent.html

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2011 12:28:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Location: http://www.example.com/ajaxcontent.html
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

---

Sitemap and robots.txt are included as recommended.

To me it seems like everything is working as it should - but googlebot is not able to see any content?
Pages aren´t indexed either yet - but as I read it could take a while.
I have updated the page 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what you should expect to see - googlebot doesn't follow 301s immediately, and it is the following request that sees content.

Does your site map link to the non-ajax version of the page? Although the 301s should work, having links that don't go through the 301 can't hurt.

Are the links to the Ajax pages regular HTML links? Googlebot won't click on something that looks like a button.

Comment: thanks for your answer! my sitemap links to the "www.abc.com/#!ajaxcontent.html"- pages, as I don´t want those to be indexed as "www.abc.com/ajaxcontent.html" in the search-results. which is just the page the bot is supposed to see. the links are regular html links implemented as "a href=www.abc.com/#!ajaxcontent.html".